# Order terms by count - missing terms

Tags: query, order, terms, count

I have this problem: I'm using get_terms with ordering by count.
And some terms are missing - I have no idea why, there is no exlude, or hide posts or anything like this.

What is wrong?
Here is the code:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("autorzy", array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC'));
    $count = count($terms);
    if ( $count > 0 ){
    echo "<div>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
<?php echo $term->name; ?>
<a href="<?php get_term_link( $term ); ?>" class="avatar-link"></a>
<?php echo term_description( $term->term_id, 'autorzy' ) ?>
    <?php } echo "</div>"; } ?>
```

EDIT: this term isn't empty, and that problem is only with orderby count.
Now is set "name" and it shows:

http://wszystkoconajwazniejsze.pl/autorzy/
my problem is with the last one - Lemańska.

Comment: Do these missing terms have a count? Or are they zero? Is there more than one post type in the autorzy taxonomy? Can you show us a term thats missing in the backend? What happens if there's no term name/link/description? Perhaps the term is listed but the markup is empty? What if you use `!is_wp_error( $terms )` instead of `count`?

Comment: Count in these missing terms are more than zero, one is 13! Which is the most here. It's only one post type (post). There is the name, description - everything. In other "orderby" it shows...

Comment: Hook a filter onto `terms_clauses` and dump the vars the filter passes you, see if there's something that looks off in the data when you call `get_terms` with the count orderby vs without.

Comment: There's no lemanska term http://wszystkoconajwazniejsze.pl/autorzy/lemanska gives me a 404 ( as does the version with the accented n). I've also updated the WP Codex example your code appears to be based on to make use of `empty()` and `is_wp_error() instead of `count()`

Comment: http://wszystkoconajwazniejsze.pl/autorzy/joanna-lemanska/ - it's like this. I just shorted in on writing.
but it still doesn't tell anything, because it's not empty and in other order it shows.

Answer (score 1):

By default `hide_empty` is `true` for get_terms. So i guess you must be missing terms which do not have posts. Try this,

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("autorzy", array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC','hide_empty'=>0 ));
    $count = count($terms);
    if ( $count > 0 ){
    echo "<div>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
<?php echo $term->name; ?>
<a href="<?php get_term_link( $term ); ?>" class="avatar-link"></a>
<?php echo term_description( $term->term_id, 'autorzy' ) ?>
    <?php } echo "</div>"; } ?>
```

Comment: No, that term is not empty, that's my main problem.